# How to iterate through TreeView elements?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I've been looking pretty much everywhere on here for an answer but could not find a working one..

I come from a VBA heavy background so I understand the syntax very well, but I still don't understand how WPF Application works in NET 6.0, lol.

The situation is as follows:

I have one TreeView element in my Application Window, it has two parents and one child each.

My VBA brain logic would say something like

```
x = 0
Do While x < TreeViewObject.Items(x).Count ' This would be the iteration for finding out parents
y = 0

Do While y < TreeViewObject.Items(x).Children.Count ' This would be the iteration for finding out how many children the parents have.

Msgbox(TreeViewObject.Items(x).Children(y)) ' prints out the children's values

y = y + 1
Loop

x = x + 1
Loop
```

..would work, but the logic here is MUCH worse than I expected, how can I iterate through a TreeView element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This demonstrates using recursion to walk a Treeview

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    IterateTV(TreeView1.Nodes(0))
End Sub

Private Sub IterateTV(nd As TreeNode)
    Debug.Write("' ")
    Debug.WriteLine(nd.Text)
    For Each tnd As TreeNode In nd.Nodes
        IterateTV(tnd)
    Next
End Sub
'TreeView1
' root
'   A
'   B
'       B sub 1
'       B sub 2
'           B sub 2 sub a
'       B sub 3
'   C
```

Comment: 'Nodes' is not a member of 'TreeView'. My TreeView is named CategoryList and it has no 'Nodes' property, this is the same property I see quoted EVERYWHERE I look and it doesn't exist.

Comment: @AvrigeanuLaurian This post is using the WinForm's TreeView, which does have a Nodes collection property.

Comment: @LarsTech, I did mention I am using WPF Application with .NET 6.0 though, anyway, I have found the solution with the help of dbasnett's code which helped me understand the logic behind the interface. See below.

Answer (score 1):

Disregarding my older post, this implementation is wholly superior:

```
        For Each VarParent In CategoryList.Items
            MsgBox(VarParent.ToString)

            For Each VarChild In VarParent.Items
                MsgBox(VarChild.ToString)
            Next

        Next
```

This method will loop through each parent, then each children it has, with logic similar to what you would find in VBA with 0 extra complications.

Old code:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    IterateTV(CategoryList)
End Sub

Private Sub IterateTV(nd)
    For Each tnd In nd.Items
        IterateTV(tnd)
        MsgBox(tnd.ToString)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Except now this won't work for nodes that are child of a child.

Comment: @LarsTech For the scope I am working on, this is sufficient, I do not have more than a parent and children, my children don't have children etc., but you would be able to extend this list with additional for each by using the logic used to create the first two for each loops.

For example, if I wanted to get the children of the children, I could just:

For Each VarChildChild in VarChild.Items
Msgbox(VarChildChild.ToString)
Next

Take care of error handling with this though.

This method also lets you check the values while it goes through it and make modifications.

Comment: Your original answer did it through recursion, so it could handle any number of child levels.  Just saying, your original answer was the "wholly superior" version.

Comment: @LarsTech my original answer did it through recursion, yes, correct, I just dislike that it has no "structure", I will edit the code in this post, maybe it'll help others. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the other answer did not seem very mentally unintensive. It may also be me that always looks for simpler ways of writing code in one sitting so I don't have to decypher what I wrote later :P.